# 403 Signature not matched in uploading a file to AWS S3 with Pre-Signed URL and ng-file-upload from Browser

Tags: amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

I am using ng-file-upload to send a file to AWS-S3 in my angular app.

```
Upload.http({
  url: '/presignedurl',
  headers : {
    'Content-Type': file.type
  },
  data: file
})
```

It is giving me 403 Forbidden error saying

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS S3 needs binary/octet-stream so you can use FileReader class in JavaScript to convert file data to binary/octet-stream

Replace your code with this

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("PUT", $scope.url);
reader.onload = function(evt) {
   xhr.send(evt.target.result);
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer($files[file]);
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for .Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
var config = {
    url: result.signed_request,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": files[0].type != '' files[0].type : 'application/octet-stream'
    },
    method: 'PUT',
    data: files[0]
};
Upload.http(config);
```

Comment: Could you give a minor explanation/insight on how your answer?